# Can we use websockets protocal in the Google Cloud run? (Not the current socket.io)

Tags: websocket, gcloud

Currently, GCloud run support socket.io for bi-directional comunication. But I am looking for websockets protocal. How can we use websockets communication in the GCloud run?

I did deploy my backend app (node.js) in the Gcloud run and found that it support only socket.io, not websockets implementation.